# The desktop of ubuntu 15.04, doesn't work

Tags: 15.04

I try to instaló ubuntu many times un muy pc, but when i replay the desktop doesn't work. It looks like a normal ubuntu desktop, but when i try to clik on  ANY icon it doesn't work. Please help me, i'm hopeless.

Comment: What do you mean by replaying? Which icon? Please reformulate your question by editing it, so that it's possible to help you.

Answer (score -2):

First logout of the system and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> which will open a terminal, then type the following:

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: What is your basis for assuming nvidia is involved here?

Comment: because all of my computers had an nvidia graphics card :) he should change that line for his graphics card.

Comment: Could you also explain in your answer what issuing these commands actually does?

Comment: ...and if they have an ati card and a desktop different from unity, you have utterly destroyed their configuration.  This is a dangerous answer as is.

Comment: I have an asus card

Comment: Ir doesn't work dai wei

Comment: Michael, I've searched the web...I only hoped that this would be useful. Sorry for being wrong.